# Blas GEMM launch failed with Tensorflow 1.13.1, CUDA 10.0 and RTX 3070

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a model with my RTX 3070 and the following libraries:

- CUDA 10.0
- cuDNN 7.4.1
- tensorflow==1.13.1
- tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1

and received the following error:

```
2021-09-27 12:15:55.299444: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:698] failed to run cuBLAS routine cublasSgemm_v2: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\clara\OneDrive\Desktop\greenfield\greenfield\venv-win\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\clara\OneDrive\Desktop\greenfield\greenfield\venv-win\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\clara\OneDrive\Desktop\greenfield\greenfield\venv-win\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(64, 496), b.shape=(496, 1024), m=64, n=1024, k=496
         [[{{node audio/Encoder/Encoder/while/Encoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/MatMul}}]]
         [[{{node gradients/CNN/res_block_1_second_bn/FusedBatchNorm_grad/FusedBatchNormGrad}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(64, 496), b.shape=(496, 1024), m=64, n=1024, k=496
         [[node audio/Encoder/Encoder/while/Encoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/MatMul (defined at C:\Users\clara\OneDrive\Desktop\greenfield\greenfield\avsr\encoder.py:292) ]]
         [[node gradients/CNN/res_block_1_second_bn/FusedBatchNorm_grad/FusedBatchNormGrad (defined at C:\Users\clara\OneDrive\Desktop\greenfield\greenfield\avsr\seq2seq.py:222) ]]
```

Comment: Are you even sure that that rather elderly Tensorflow version even has or can have support for your extremely new GPU?

Comment: @talonmies yeah I suspect that's the problem.. however, the repo that I'm trying to adopt requires tensorflow 1.13.1 so I'm kinda stuck TT

Comment: CUDA 11.1 is the first toolkit release with native support for your GPU. You could try building  Tensorflow 1.13.1 from source  with a toolkit and matching CUDNN version with support for your GPU and see if it helps